# Using TWriter.WriteString two extra bytes are saved

Tags: delphi

In Delphi 10.4.2, when I use the TWriter.WriteString two extra bytes are saved :

```
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  Writer: TWriter;
begin
    FileStream := TFileStream.Create('stream.txt', fmCreate or fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyNone);
    Writer := TWriter.Create(FileStream, $FF);
    try
      Writer.WriteString('2');
    finally
      Writer.Free;
      FileStream.free;
    end
end;
```

[image]

What are these two bytes? How can I ignore them?

Comment: Are you aware that TWriter is an internal class used to stream components (so it is not for writing text files)? Maybe you want to use [TTextWriter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TTextWriter.Write)?

Comment: But in this example it is the opposite :
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/TWriter_(Delphi)

Comment: You probably missed this sentence in TWriter documentation: "TWriter is used internally by the component streaming system to write information associated with a component, such as published properties of components or custom property data, to a stream.". As far as streaming in concerned, when reading back the TReader need to know what data to read and the size of data to read.

Comment: Note that the paired example using TReader reads back the string correctly. Just the stream format isn't simple text so the examples are not really suitable for reading files not created by the same code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design of `TWriter.WriteString`. Probably your use case is not the correct one.

The first byte ($06) is the value type (`TValueType.vaString` for your code). The second byte is the length of the string (1 byte for you).

You can find all that information in the source code provided by Embarcadero in file `System.Classes.pas`.

You cannot ignore them. Maybe you can use `TStream.Write` to write your string without extra payload?

Comment: It should be noted that `TWriter.WriteString()` can store a `string` in one of 4 different formats, depending on which one produces the fewest bytes in the stream: `vaString` (type $06, 1-byte length, `AnsiChar` payload), `vaLString` (type $0C, 4-byte length, `AnsiChar` payload), `vaUTF8String` ($14, 4-byte length, `Byte` payload) or `vaWString` (type $12, 4-byte length, `WideChar` payload)